# Reading Data From Access Database in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working on Invoice Software. I get struct in reading data from Access database. My question is about when i type 1st word of Product name the program do search in database and then show me related products names as traditional Billing software do. How can i do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AutoComplete Extende](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/autocomplete-extender-using-Asp-Net/)r if you are creating a web application or [AutoCompleteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of TextBox if it is a Windows desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextBox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strProvider = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = F:\product.accdb";
        string strSql = "Select * from product where productname like '" + textBox1.Text + "*';" ;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable products = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(products);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = products;
        con.Close();
    }
```